# Powershell match exact string from list of lines

Tags: powershell

I  get below output from a query in powershell.I need to check if the output contains success

Output:

```
$a = '
Executing command: this command

url : https://www.google.com

Working on it...

unSucessfull!'
```

one more output, that could be returned from this

```
$a = '
    Executing command: this command

    url : https://www.google.com

    Working on it...

    Success!'
```

I need to check, If this string contains exact word "Success"

So i did below

```
$a |select-string "Success" -simplematch
```

But this matches unsuccessfull word as well

I tried many variations,but nothing helped like with out any success

```
$a -like "Success*"
```

Any pointers

Comment: `"Success"` -> `"\bSuccess\b"`

Comment: @PetSerAl this doesnt work. `$a = '
Executing command: this command

url : https://www.google.com

Working on it...

Success!

' 

cls;
$a  |Select-String -Pattern "\bSuccess!\b"`

Comment: Use -match instead of like with the \b, which binds regex to just that specific string.

Comment: @TheGameiswar That is because you use `Success!` but not `Success`.

Comment: @PetSerAl for the given example in comments, i used `Success!` in output and as well as select-string `Success!`

Comment: @m0lochwalker , below example doesnt work..`$a = '
Executing command: this command

url : https://www.google.com

Working on it...

Success!

' 

$a  -match "\bSuccess!\b"`

Comment: @TheGameiswar Inserting `!` right before `\b` change effective meaning of `\b`, that is why it does not match.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if all you want is "is that exact word in the text?" then you should use `-match` instead of `Select-String`. [*grin*] the 1st gives you a `false/true` result, but the 2nd is for finding & returning a  *string* that contains the text.

so the proper solution to "is that exact word present in the string?" is ...

```
$A -match '\bsuccess\b'
```

that checks for the search term bounded by word boundaries and gives you either `False` or `True`.

Comment: -match won't work if I have text like "abc" "abc1" "abc2" it will match all 3

Comment: @NaveenKumar - please note the `\b`. [*grin*]

Comment: I have `abc1, abc, abc2` in txt file, if want to find whether `abc` exact word exist in my file then I will get result against each word like `false true false`

Comment: @NaveenKumar - PLEASE, if the code listed does not work as expected, please start a new Question & list the code along with the part that fails to work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Regex in `Select-String` cmdlet to fulfill your requirements

Here is the example : (**Note :**  as per given text there are spaces before 'Success' )

```
$result = $a | select-string -Pattern "`r`n[\s]*Success"
```

if string does not exist in input then `$result` will be null.